# Increase the timeout when logging with external provider

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 5 Identity with Google as External login.

After I login in Google I get a 500 error when getting back to my application.

The error occurs when accessing the callback url "/signin-google" in my application.

When checking the error details it says it is a 60 seconds timeout error.

How to check of the real error is? I tried to increase the timeout using:

I tried in my application Startup's `ConfigureServices` method:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddGoogle("Google", x => {
      x.ClientId = clientId;
      x.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
      x.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240);
    });
```

But strangely I get the same 60 seconds timeout error.

Comment: Hi @Miguel Moura, I think you need change the time for `BackchannelTimeout`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked out.

Comment: Hi @Miguel Moura, I have update to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check of the real error is? I tried to increase the timeout
> using:

You need change the time for `BackchannelTimeout`.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.remoteauthenticationoptions.backchanneltimeout?view=aspnetcore-5.0